# Declare node module for TypeScript that is not available within typings

Tags: node.js, typescript, declaration, command-line-arguments

I'm quite new to TypeScript and am trying to script a little cli app.

I want to use npm~command-line-args but its definition is not available with `typings` so I thought how hard could it be to create my own. Turns out it is harder than I expected.

So my goal is to export a module which exposes just a single function and maybe a small type declaration.

I tried this so far:

```
declare module 'command-line-args' {
  export interface cliOptionDefinition {
    name: string,
    alias?: string,
    type: BooleanConstructor|StringConstructor|NumberConstructor,
    multiple?: Boolean,
    defaultOption?: any
  }

  export = function commandLineArgs <R> ( optionDefinitions: cliOptionDefinition[] ) {};
}
```

But am getting this error:
`error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.`

Answer (score 0):

Does:

```
export function commandLineArgs <R> ( optionDefinitions: cliOptionDefinition[] );
```

work the way that you would expect? (Omit the `=`, and the `{}`.) If you are intending to provide an implementation of `commandLineArgs`, then you want to export it from a non-ambient (remove `declare` etc.), preferably external, module (or, alternatively, namespace).

Comment: I tried that within the module declaration. But this leads to a wrong compiled js file where it is like this: `const command_line_args_1 = require('command-line-args'); /* ... */ const options = command_line_args_1.commandLineArgs(optionDefinitions);`

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at the Polymer projects (e.g. [polymer-cli](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/)) - they use command-line-args with Typescript..